# How to save data in JTable to database?

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

Currently I creating an import Excel file function, here is my code:

```
    private void fromExcelMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       

        File excelFile;
        FileInputStream excelFIS = null;
        BufferedInputStream excelBIS = null;
        XSSFWorkbook excelJTableImport = null;

        DefaultTableModel model =  (DefaultTableModel) tabelsatuan.getModel();

        String defaultCurrentDirectoryPath = "";
        JFileChooser excelFileChooser = new JFileChooser(defaultCurrentDirectoryPath);

        FileNameExtensionFilter fnef = new FileNameExtensionFilter("EXCEL FILES","xls","xlsx","xlsm");
        excelFileChooser.setFileFilter(fnef);
        excelFileChooser.setDialogTitle("Select Excel File");
        int excelChooser =  excelFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (excelChooser == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            try{
            excelFile = excelFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            excelFIS = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
            excelBIS = new BufferedInputStream(excelFIS);
            excelJTableImport = new XSSFWorkbook(excelBIS);
            XSSFSheet excelSheet = excelJTableImport.getSheetAt(0);

            for (int row = 0; row < excelSheet.getLastRowNum(); row++ ){
               XSSFRow excelRow = excelSheet.getRow(row); 

               XSSFCell excelNomor = excelRow.getCell(0);
               XSSFCell excelKode = excelRow.getCell(1);
               XSSFCell excelNama = excelRow.getCell(2);
               XSSFCell excelKeterangan = excelRow.getCell(3);


               model.addRow(new Object[] {excelNomor,excelKode,excelNama,excelKeterangan});

            }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Imported Successfully");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }finally {
                try{
                if(excelFIS != null){
                    excelFIS.close();
                }
                if(excelBIS != null){
                    excelBIS.close();
                }
                if(excelJTableImport != null){
                   excelJTableImport.close();
                }
                }catch(IOException ex){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But, it only show the data on the table without actually saving it to the Database, so when I close it the imported data is all gone. I tried to make a Save to database button using this code:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tabelsatuan.getModel();
        try{
            Statement st;
            st = con.createStatement();
            for(int x=0; x<model.getRowCount();x++){
                st.executeUpdate("update satuan set kode='"+model.getValueAt(x, 1)+"',nama='"+model.getValueAt(x, 2)+"',keterangan='"+model.getValueAt(x, 3)+"' where nomor="+model.getValueAt(x,0));
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Saved");
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

But it doesn't work. How can I save the data in a `JTable` to database?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"it doesn't work"* Why does it fail? Note that code example has poor exception reporting. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Use a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) when creating your SQL string. The code is easier to read and maintain, so you are less likely to make SQL errors.